# How to populate a combo-box in EDIT FORM

Tags: php, mysql, forms, combobox

please help me. I include here (see bellow) the Combobox script for INSERTING FORM
I have a Form of Adding a new product. One of option is to select what Category. So, Combobox is for selecting Category from.

```
<TD>

<?php

$sql="SELECT categories.id as id, categories.name as name FROM categories";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id=$row["id"];
$thing=$row["name"];
$options.= " <OPTION VALUE=".$id.">".$thing.'</option>';
    }

?>

<select name="CATEGORY" onClick=”submitCATEGORY();”>
 <option value="0">Select Category
 <?php echo $options;?></option>

</select>   
</TD>
```

Now, I would like to have an EDIT FORM using the same script as for Inserting data in database using combobox.

`<?php echo $CATEGORY; ?>` this script is for retrieving the data from database.

please help me to find a way, when I want to Edit a PRODUCT information to get combobox with option I selected during the inserting the data...
I could succeed to fill the data for the name of products and other information, only Combobox is empty. I hope you could understand what I want to achieve! Thank you in advance for your time!!!

See bellow what I tried but did not succede:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT categories.id as id, categories.name as name FROM categories";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$options="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id=$row["id"];
$thing=$row["name"];
$options.= " <OPTION VALUE=".$id.">".$thing.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    <select name="CATEGORY" onClick=”submitCATEGORY();”>
<option value="<?php echo $CATEGORY; ?>">
<?php echo $options;?></option>
</select>
</TD>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your edit page,

```
<?php
 $CATEGORY = 3; //from DB table, consider 3 as category id for sample

 $sql="SELECT categories.id as id, categories.name as name FROM categories";
 $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 $options="";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row["id"];
    $thing=$row["name"];
    $isSel = ($CATEGORY == $id)?"selected":'';
    $options.= " <OPTION VALUE='$id' $isSel>$thing</option>';
 }
 ?>
 <select name="CATEGORY" onClick=”submitCATEGORY();”>
 <option value="<?php echo $CATEGORY; ?>">
 <?php echo $options;?></option>
 </select>
 </TD>
```

Comment: Thank You very much! I have couple of days already lost with this stuff! you solved my life! Briliant!!!

Comment: @SergiuCostas, plz accept the answer so that the question will not be listed in the unanswered section.

Comment: tell me please, I have in my form one more Combobox for Tax... the same story like Category... Shall I proceed like $isSel = ($TAXES == $id)?"selected":'';

Comment: @SergiuCostas, ofcourse; give it a try and let me know if you have any issues

Comment: AFAIK it's more or less exactly the same as I suggested :)

Comment: @Riho, Yes. What i have given is the ready made solution-improvised version ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then on Edit form you should mark the option that should be selected with 'selected ' tag:

```
<Option value="2" selected="selected">2</Option>
```

Comment: it is not just like this: Categories is a culomn from Mysql. So when I add a new Product, combobox select me a category for new product from mysql. Now I want to Edit the information about new added product in a form. When I select the product - the form is fulfiling with information from mysql, with the exemption of combobox for selecting Category. So I want to achieve that combobox to show  that option I have selected for the product before. Thank You for asking

Comment: In your Edit sample there is no value assigned when you use $CATEGORY - maybe just a typo

Comment: I put a small part of my project.. just that part where I can not achieve the result :) Also, I show that by <?php echo $CATEGORY; ?> I can get the result for category from database, but I do not how to use it for combobox to show me what category represents :) thank you very much for your time and your support! much appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

Tryt this..If I understood corectly than:-

```
<option value="your_id" <?php echo $CATEGORY == your_id ?'selected':'';?>>your_category_name</option>
```

here $CATEGORY will be the retriving data from table

for your edit page you should do like this:-

```
<option value="1" <?php echo $CATEGORY == 1 ?'selected':'';?> ><?php echo $options;?></option>
```

Comment: what`s means your_value? I have more then 2.000 of products which have everyone its own category about 25 of them. I want to achieve to insert a new product and to edit it. The first part to insert I have already achieved, but editing it, I can not achive that combobox show me what category is related to that product. Hope it make more clear :) thank you for yor try

Comment: As I understood that combo box displays the categories, right?... And $CATEGORY is the category stored in the mysql column, right?...So here I checked , is both values are same or not!..if it is same than it will be selected....Hope I am on correct way to explain. :)

Comment: not sure I could understand your question. But some additional imput: When I introduce a new Product I have to introduce in column Category - the id of table CATEGORIES... So in my script you can see there are two variables: ID and Name. So compobox show name but inserting ID... later on, by <?php echo $CATEGORY;?> I am calling back the ID, but I can not succede that combobox to show me the NAME of Category related to that ID

Comment: yeah, there's soln , u are getting ID in  $CATEGORY field,correct?,,,,So what u have to do..is just put that ID value which is storing in the table's column.. as $CATEGORY(it is value stored in column) = ID(it is value you given)

Comment: yes, but I need that combobox to show me the NAME which represent that ID. Otherwords, I want to see product with Category Option already selected

Comment: Hmmm....follow the code...I think you get know much clarification. If any confusion that tell me... :) It shows the NAME which represents the ID from which you r going to check that, this category is selected or not.

Comment: there is two PHP forms: Inserting and Editing... Inserting form: I Select a combobox a value for Category... But in the Editing Form - I want to have combobox already selected with the option I made in Inserting Form

Comment: value="<?php echo $CATEGORY; ?>".....why this.....just have form as Inserting form. You only have to check for value. As I shown in edited code for you

Comment: I try your script, the result was a blank combobox :( and I have posibility to select a category, but it should be the combobox with selected category for that specific product